# DateTime Issue with Laravel 5.2 & MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

Found this, but it didn't help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/timestampdatetime-issue-with-51-sqlserver

When I set my date field on the model like so `protected $dates = ['OrderDate','TimeStamp'];` then call     `$order->OrderDate` I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
The separation symbol could not be found
The format separator does not match
Trailing data'
```

But, if I manually create a Carbon date object using the same formatting and copying\pasting the date directly from SQL Server, it does so successfully:

```
>>> Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.000', '2015-12-29 00:00:00.000');
=> Carbon\Carbon {#835
    +"date": "2015-12-29 00:00:00.000000",
    +"timezone_type": 3,
    +"timezone": "UTC",
   }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason Laravel was seeing it as `M j Y h:i:s:000A` -- probably the driver. I added `protected $dateFormat = 'M j Y h:i:s:000A';` to all the MS SQL Server models I am using.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, 

Your solution is working in my end but I'm wondering if there's any other solution aside from setting the $dateFormat? Is this issue related to the SQL driver or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The workaround would be to setup accessors and mutators and parse date manually, instead of putting it in $dates array.

Something like that:

```
public function getOrderDateAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.000', $value);
}

public function getTimeStampAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.000', $value);
}

public function setOrderDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['OrderDate'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.000');
}

public function setTimeStampAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['TimeStamp'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.000', $value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.000');
}
```